# Update of MySQL table column to sequential digit based on another column

Tags: mysql

**The current table looks something like this:**

```
[id | section | order | thing]
[1  | fruits  | 0     | apple]
[2  | fruits  | 0     | banana]
[3  | fruits  | 0     | avocado]
[4  | veggies | 0     | tomato]
[5  | veggies | 0     | potato]
[6  | veggies | 0     | spinach]
```

**I'm wondering how to make the table look more like this:**

```
[id | section | order | thing]
[1  | fruits  | 1     | apple]
[2  | fruits  | 2     | banana]
[3  | fruits  | 3     | avocado]
[4  | veggies | 1     | tomato]
[5  | veggies | 2     | potato]
[6  | veggies | 3     | spinach]
```

"order" column updated to a sequential number, starting at 1, based on "section" column and "id" column.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with an `update` by using a `join`.  The second table to the join calculates the ordering, which is then used for the update:

```
update t join
       (select t.*, @rn := if(@prev = t.section, @rn + 1, 1) as rn
        from t cross join (select @rn := 0, @prev := '') const
       ) tsum
       on t.id = tsum.id
    set t.ordering = tsum.rn
```

Comment: Looks about right, but I got this error:
#1267 - Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='

Comment: @JackieAD . . . Your column is not using the default collation.  Try changing `@prev := ''` to `@prev := '' collate utf8_unicode_ci`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to do this as an `UPDATE`, as that will be really slow.

Instead, do this on `INSERT`.  Here's a simple one-line `INSERT` that will grab the next order number and inserts a record called 'kiwi' in the section 'fruits'.

```
INSERT INTO `table_name` (`section`, `order`, `thing`)
SELECT 'fruits', MAX(`order`) + 1, 'kiwi'
FROM `table_name` 
WHERE `section` = `fruits`
```

EDIT: You could also do this using an insert trigger, e.g.:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `trigger_name` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `table_name`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.`order` = (SELECT MAX(`order`) + 1 FROM `table_name` WHERE `section` = NEW.`section`);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then you could just insert your records as usual, and they will auto-update the `order` value.

```
INSERT INTO `table_name` (`section`, `thing`)
VALUES ('fruits', 'kiwi')
```

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that this would only be useful for future inserts and not for fixing the order values in the data currently inside of the table?

Comment: @JackieAD - Yes, the above solutions would prevent your data from ever getting in a state that needs updating.   Assuming you could start with a new, empty table, this would be your ideal solution.  Or you could run your update one time and switch to this in the future to prevent having to update again.

Comment: But what update operation? That's what I'm looking for a solution to still.

Comment: Ideally, I would have known I needed an order column from the start, but the data is already in there and needs to be updated.

Comment: Ok, even so, you should add this functionality so you won't need to update again in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than storing the ordering, you could derive it:

```
SELECT t.id
      ,t.section
      ,@row_num := IF (@prev_section = t.section, @row_num+1, 1) AS ordering
      ,t.thing
      ,@prev_section := t.section
  FROM myTable t
      ,(SELECT @row_num := 1) x
      ,(SELECT @prev_value := '') y
  ORDER BY t.section, t.id
```

Note that `order` is a keyword and is therefore not the greatest for a column name. You could quote the column name or give it a different name...